# Frida - Failed to enumerate applications: enumerate_applications() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'

Tags: android, android-emulator, frida

I'm having issues trying to run Frida on MacOS (12.3) to an android emulator (8.1).

I have downloaded 'frida-server-15.1.17-android-x86.xz' and put this on the emulator in /data/local/tmp.
I also made this executable with chmod +x and run it on the emulator.

Now i have objection and frida installed on my macbook and I'm trying to run `frida-ps -Uai`.

This is where I get the error as mentioned in the title.

`Failed to enumerate applications: enumerate_applications() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'`

Please if somebody knows the fix or a work around for this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for responding. I've that version of frida now. But still it's not working and showing `Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name 'com.androidpentesting.securestore'`.
But now the output version is 15.1.17

Answer (score 1):

The installed frida-version and the version of frida-server should be the same. The error `got an unexpected keyword argument` indicates that you might use different (incompatible) versions.
Check `frida-ps --version`. It should output 15.1.17

Furthermore Frida has a bug that is unresolved for months that makes it impossible to use the app package name when connecting from command-line. Instead you have to use the app name or the process id shown in the output of `frida-ps -Uai.`